# Nginx, put HTTP AUTH login to header

Tags: nginx, header, http-auth

How to put HTTP AUTH login to header ? Something like:

```
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
proxy_set_header Username $Login_here;
```

any ideas ?

Comment: The variable is called `$remote_user`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_remote_user) for details.

Comment: When I try add value to proxy_set_header, i get error:
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
[emerg] 8691#0: invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:13

Comment: Did you terminate the line with a `;`? BTW, all of the auth headers seem to be passed through the proxy anyway.